# Deploying AngularJS Seed application in WebStorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I recently started to learn about AngularJS and came across WebStorm and the AngularJS plugin by John Lindquist. Started by creating a new project using the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project and imported to WebStorm using File -> Open Directory. My directory structure looks like this

[image]

Now when I try to Debug it I get a 404 error. If I move the file app/index.html to the root folder and adjust all URL's to begin with app then it works fine. Is there a way to keep the default folder structure without moving the index.html to the root folder and also make it work with WebStorm?

I am using WebStorm 6.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

I use WebStorm 7, so there might be some discrepancy in comparison with version 6 that you're using, but the over-all functionality is the same.

Quick solution:
Open the file in the editor and right click in the code to access the context menu. Choose the "Debug" option, which should start a debug session pointing to the current page.

Configuration solution:
WebStorm supports configurations for setting up different debugging scenarios. From the "Run" menu, choose the "Configurations" option. Add a JavaScript debug configuration, and add the URL you want in the designated field within the dialog presented.

Then, when you initialize a debugging session (a general one, not one for a specific page), you're presented a small dialog that allows you to choose a debug configuration.

Maybe there are more options or ways to accomplish the same thing as well, but I've never really given it more thought. I hope this is a working solution for you, but if not there's alway the documentation. If you need further clarification with regard to my answer, just give me a comment.